# Reading Numbers that don''t exist from a file - C

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I am trying to read from a file I've written to.
The text file contains:

```
1  
VA1 01 01 01 01 BAS 01 01 01 01
```

Where 1 is the number of flights stored in the file and everything below it is the flight details. I want to know how I can read and turn the first character into an integer and then have a for loop using the integer printing the amount of lines below.

```
flight_t loadFlights(char flightDatabase[50], int totalflights, flight_t f[MAX_NUM_FLIGHTS]) {
  int counter;
  FILE * fp;
  fp = fopen("database.txt", "r");

  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Read error\n");
    return *f;
  }

  sscanf(fp, "%d", & totalflights);

  for (counter = 0; counter <= totalflights; counter++) {
    fscanf(fp, "%s %d %d %d %d %s %d %d %d %d", f[counter].flightcode, & f[counter].departure_dt.month, & f[counter].departure_dt.date, & f[counter].departure_dt.hour, & f[counter].departure_dt.minute,
      f[counter].arrival_citycode, & f[counter].arrival_dt.month, & f[counter].arrival_dt.date, & f[counter].arrival_dt.hour, & f[counter].arrival_dt.minute);
    printf("%s %02d %02d %02d %02d %s %02d %02d %02d %02d\r\n",
      f[counter].flightcode, f[counter].departure_dt.month, f[counter].departure_dt.date,
      f[counter].departure_dt.hour, f[counter].departure_dt.minute,
      f[counter].arrival_citycode, f[counter].arrival_dt.month,
      f[counter].arrival_dt.date, f[counter].arrival_dt.hour,
      f[counter].arrival_dt.minute);
    totalflights++;
  }

  printf("%d\n", totalflights);
  fclose(fp);
  return *f;

}
```

However specifically the line sscanf it is printing this error:
[image: Error]

a) how do I get the first character into an int
b) how do I start printing from the second line in the text file.

[image: ERROR USING fscanf]

```
struct flight {
    char flightcode[MAX_FLIGHTCODE_LEN+1]; /*Char as the code e.g. 125620 will be read as characters not an integer as you dont need to apply any mathematics to the code*/
    char arrival_citycode[MAX_CITYCODE_LEN+1]; /*Add +1 to leave room for the null character /0 so you get you full word length rather than 'fligh' */
    date_time_t departure_dt; /*use the date structure types*/
    date_time_t arrival_dt; /*same as above*/
 };
 typedef struct flight flight_t;
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170357/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-angus-ryan).

Comment: regarding: `sscanf(fp, "%d", & totalflights);` this statement has a few problems.  1) `sscanf()` is for reading from a buffer already in memory, not for reading from a file.  2) the `totalflights` is an item in the parameter list (I.E. on the call function call block) so the address is some place on that function call block, NOT the address of the data in the callers' function. I.E, the caller should have passed the address of the data in their function and the signature for `loadFlights()` should be saying: `int *totalflights`

Comment: regarding the home grown type: `flight_t` That is not defined anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces. 2) variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage`.  'f'` is meaningless, even in the current context.  3) honor the right margin (column 72 or 80) by breaking statements up and the additional lines being indented.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: these functions don't set `errno` to anything useful, so need to use: `fprintf( stderr, "...\n", ... );` to report the error.  2) when using the input format specifiers: '%s' and/or '%[...]' always use a MAX FIELD WIDTH modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those input specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input. This avoids any possibility of buffer overflow and the attendant undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `for (counter = 0;
        counter <= totalflights;
        counter++)` and at the end of the `for()` body is: `totalflights++;`  so this loop will never end, until the program crashes

Comment: suggest using a `while()` loop instead of a `for()` loop and use the call to `fscanf()` as the loop control

Comment: this `return *f;` states that the parameter `f` will be returned, but this: `flight_t loadFlights(,,,)` states that a `flight_t` will be returned, not the whole array